# Как создать кнопку, добавляющую бота в канал?

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram, aiogram-2.x

Кнопка должна сначала показать пользователю список каналов, а после выбора канала предложить изменить права бота в этом канале. Видел эту функцию во многих ботах но сам без понятия как сделать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл ответ - нужно всего лишь добавить в кнопку ссылку

```
https://t.me/your_bot_username?startchannel&admin=post_messages
```

Если вам нужно несколько прав администратора, их нужно перечислить через "+", например:

```
https://t.me/your_bot_username?startchannel&admin=post_messages+edit_messages
```